# Accessing Webmethods from Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have a WebMethod method defined in one of my class library, which i want to access in aspx page.

I have class library project, where i have created a class which is inheriting System.UI.Page, this new class has a webmethod function called ("GetUsername"). Now i have referenced this library in my web project, and in default.aspx.cs i have inherited new class (the one i had created above in class library). Now in aspx i have wrote a ajax function to access the data from database, however it throws error for the ajax url parameter with 404.

Here's my whole code structure:

1. Class Library:

```
[ScriptService]
    public class WebMethodLibrary : Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static object GetCurrentUserName()
        {
            Alistar.Data.AlistarDataContext db = new Alistar.Data.AlistarDataContext();
            Guid gUser = new Guid("8FEF8333-F1AE-4E9E-95F9-07316CE39F73");
            var user = db.Users.Find(gUser);
            return new { Username = user.Username };
        }
    }
```

2. WebPage code behind:

```
public partial class _default : WebMethodLibrary
    {
    }
```

3. aspx Page with Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'GetCurrentUserName',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {},
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Could anyone point out what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify the name of your aspx page before method name in url You have mentioned that name of your page is default.aspx if it's in root so call will be similar to below or you have to prepend the name of your directory before page name.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '~/default.aspx/GetCurrentUserName',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {},
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```